# Connectedness of the set having a fixed distance from a closed set 2

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, path-connected

This question is related to this one: [Connectedness of the set having a fixed distance from a closed set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378627/connectedness-of-the-set-having-a-fixed-distance-from-a-closed-set). Suppose $F$ is a closed and connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>1$). Suppose the complement  of $F$ is connected and let
$$A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: dist(x, F)=\delta\}, $$ where $\delta>0$ is fixed, and $dist$ is the Euclidean distance.  If $F$ is unbounded with empty interior,  can the complement of $A$  still have a bounded component?

Comment: How about $n=3$, $F$ consists of the $x$-axis from $-\infty$ to $-2$ followed by a 0.1-dense continuous curve on the sphere of radius 2 about the origin followed by a line from 2 to $\infty$; and $\delta=1$. There is a component of $A$ inside the sphere (close to the unit sphere) and there is a component outside the sphere.

Comment: Or in $n=2$, an almost-complete arc of a circle, together with some ray heading to infinity to make it unbounded.

Comment: The complement of $F$ must be connected. Is this the case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a picture of the set $F$ (in red) in my comment above (the black lines represent the sphere of radius 2). There is a component of $A$ inside the sphere and a component outside the sphere.

[image: The set F]

Comment: The complement of $F$ must be connected. It seems to me that in your counter example this not the case. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @M.Rahmat  $F$ is the red line, and its complement is connected

Comment: @ Anthony Quas  I see. Thanks.  Your construction is very good,  but could you please tell me what you mean by 0.1-dense continuous curve? I have also another question (it was not in the question that I asked but to better understand): Is the complement of $A $ in your construction still connected, or disconnected because of the component of $A$ that is inside the ball? Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: 0.1-dense in the sphere means that for each point in the sphere, there is a point on the curve at most 0.1 away. I think the complement of $A$ has three components: two components where $d(x,F)>1$: one of these is approximately the unit ball; and the other one an infinite component consisting of everything outside (in the everyday sense) of a fattened version of $F$. The third component is things where the distance to $F$ is strictly between 0 and 1.

Comment: @ Anthony Quas.  It seems to me that the component of $A$ that is inside the sphere of radius 2 is not a complete sphere, but a smaller copy of $F$ on the sphere of radius 2; i.e. it is a 0.1-dense continuous curve around the sphere of radius 1. Could you tell me what you think?

Comment: No. Everything on the sphere of radius 2 is at most 0.1 away from $F$. The finite part of $A$ consists of points of radius approximately 1: points of radius 1 are exactly 1 unit from the sphere of radius 2 and approximately 1 away from $F$.